# ssh port forwarding with permament connection between remote and destination

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel, socket

I know you can use ssh to forward a local or remote port to another destination and port. So for example let's say I have this command:

```
ssh -L *:8443:10.0.0.1:443 user@10.0.0.2
```

So this allow to open a listening socket on the machine where the command is issued (let's say that its ip is `10.0.0.3`) on port `8443`. When some client connect to `10.0.0.3:8443` the packets flow through the ssh channel established between `10.0.0.3` and `10.0.0.2` then the ssh server on `10.0.0.2` forward the packets to the destination which is in this case 10.0.0.1:443.

I'm wondering if the server `10.0.0.2` can makes a permanent connection to `10.0.0.1:443` so that the connection `10.0.0.2:xxxxx -> 10.0.0.1:443` is opened once and never dropped. All the traffic coming from the clients connecting to `10.0.0.3:8443` should use this permanent channel.

So basically I don't want that when a new client connect to `10.0.0.3:8443` a new channel `10.0.0.2:xxxxx -> 10.0.0.1:443` is established. This prevent me from reusing the same session and invalidate a the request sent by another client after the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot do this with SSH. And such a generic approach would not be a good idea in the first place anyway.

TCP is a byte stream and not a message protocol. This means if multiple clients send messages in parallel, then the messages might be mixed up. The resulting data might start with the beginning of msgA from client A, continue with parts from msgB from client B, the continue with another part from msgA etc.

Thus, instead of a generic approach one would actually need a mixer which understands the specific application protocol spoken and would make sure that the message syntax in the merged data stream is preserved, no matter how the clients send the messages.

Note that this would be different with UDP since UDP is message based. But your use case seems to be TCP.

Comment: Yes in my case the protocol is HTTP so TCP at the network level.

Comment: @Bemipefe: In this case you would need some mixer which can merge HTTP traffic and keep it as proper HTTP. Maybe haproxy can do what you need - see the chapter *Keep-alive and server side connection pooling* in [this blog entry](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/http-keep-alive-pipelining-multiplexing-and-connection-pooling/).